# Simple Rookie HTML

Tags: html, css

A quick HTML question. I'm a newb and this has stumped me for hours. Using a custom HTML module in Joomla I cannot seem to get the contents to align properly. The error occurs in all browsers **except Firefox**.

In the top right of the page there is a heading "Welcome to Rib Advisor". Underneath is a Facebook login buttom that in IE, Chrome, Safari won't line up with the "Login" and "Register". See it here http://www.ribadvisor.com

Hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong. The HTML code I am using is:

```
<h3><div style="padding-top: 35px !important; margin-bottom: -12px !important; color: #f26f14;">Welcome to Rib Advisor</div></h3>
<a href="#login_lb" data-lightbox="on">Login</a>
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="login_lb" style="width: 270px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; background-color: #1f1f1f;">{module 210}</div>
</div>
<span><a href="http://www.ribadvisor.com/my-rib-advisor/register">|Register|</a></span> <span style="float: right;">{module 200}</span>
```

Cheers

Comment: using inline styles is bad practice, you should have a separate CSS file with your styles

Comment: I'm just learning and haven't quite got to how to link somehting like this to a css file. Thankyou though!

Comment: If you are learning then linking css file should be in higher priority list and play with firebug addon in firefox or developer tools if you are using chrome(ctrl+shift+i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `span` (containing the `iframe`) a `display: inline-block` setting, remove the `float: right` you gave it, and it'll work.

```
 <span style="float: right;">{module 200}</span>
```

Should be:

```
<span style="display: inline-block">{module 200}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width` to the following class

```
.tm-headerbar .uk-panel
{
  width:280px;
}
```

[image: Check the screenshot]

Comment: I'm just saying there's no need of removing the max width. Your solution should actually be only adding the width.